# Using the AQL traversal

Tags: graph, arangodb, aql

I want to use AQL to traverse a graph,I start from a vertex, I don't know how many layers of relationships, I want to go through the end,I want this traversal not to be influenced by direction,Is there any way to do it?Thank you for coming to help me.

Comment: Your question is very general and is answered with like generality by the AQL documentation - see i.p. https://docs.arangodb.com/3.2/Manual/Graphs/Traversals/. SO is not meant to substitute for reading documentation. When you have a question which can be formulated according to the guidelines at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve please feel free to ask it here.

Answer (score 1):

> Following edges in both, inbound and outbound direction, can be achieved with ANY. Unlimited traversal depth is not directly supported, but you can use an arbitrary high number for the maximum depth.

The same question was answered on [GitHub](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/4103) by Simran-B.